# EER diagram in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, database, workbench, eer-model

I need to make an EER diagram of my database. When I connect my database to MySQL Workbench it puts lines only between two tables with a FK on them. Do I need to manually put in the other lines where I don't have FK's but I connect two tables with a third middle one?

Is this EER diagram a logical (conceptual) database or a physical database? What exactly is a logical database? A logical database is a blueprint of the database. But how do I describe tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Workbench make entity-relation schema of your database.

[Here you can find some good info](http://blog.infoadvisors.com/index.php/articles/what-are-conceptual-logical-and-physical-data-models/) and [here in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design#Logically_structuring_data)

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL Workbench you can create a logical diagram. It is misnamed in MySQL Workbench as an "EER diagram" as far as I know. A logical diagram such as in MySQL can be created on the basis of an EER diagram.

An example of an EER diagram from Wiki is:

[image: EER diagram]

Comment: Thank's for the answer. It will be handy for other users.